# Form still posting even after canceling

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've read all the posts on this but can't seem to work out why my form is still posting even after I press cancel on the confirm popup. Any help appreciated. I'm returning the the result of the confirm, so i was expecting the dialog to just disappear and the form to not post.  Im sure its something simple.

Here is my code:

```
<form action='/auth/deleteUserCascade' method='post' onsubmit='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this user?\");'>
    <button type='submit' class='btn-link'>
        <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i>
    </button>";
</form>
```

Comment: Confirm function should return false on cancel

Comment: Why do you have `\"` within the confirm? drop the `\\`

Comment: You don't need to escape quotes if they're within single quotes.

Comment: You just have a typo in your onsubmit string. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you had written a wrong syntax. Next variant works as well(I used double quotes instead of single ones):

```
<form action="/auth/deleteUserCascade" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');">
  <button type="submit" class="btn-link">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem it seems. thank all for looking at this for me to help solve.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action='' method='post'>
    <button type='submit' class='btn-link' onclick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?");'>
        <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'>hello</i>
    </button>";
</form>
```

You have some weird things going on in that onsubmit string. Namely, escaping quotes unnecessarily.

Comment: Please don't link to 3rd party sites for code. Just include a code snippet right in your answer.